# After initializing a dynamic char array, all signs are equal to zeros

Tags: c

I'm trying to write the kernel in C, without stdlib and other libraries, all dynamic char arrays written in advance and without using calloc or malloc, here is an example code:

```
char* d="hello world!!!";
print_char(d[0],-1,-1,RED_ON_WHITE);

int print_char(char c, int col, int row, char attr) {
    unsigned char *vidmem = (unsigned char*) VIDEO_ADDRESS;
    int offset;
    if (col >= 0 && row >= 0) offset = get_offset(col, row);
    else offset = get_cursor_offset();

    vidmem[offset] = c;
    vidmem[offset+1] = attr;
    offset += 2;

    set_cursor_offset(offset);
    return offset;
}

int get_cursor_offset() {
    port_byte_out(REG_SCREEN_CTRL, 14);
    int offset = port_byte_in(REG_SCREEN_DATA) << 8; /* High byte: << 8 */
    port_byte_out(REG_SCREEN_CTRL, 15);
    offset += port_byte_in(REG_SCREEN_DATA);
    return offset * 2; /* Position * size of character cell */
}

void set_cursor_offset(int offset) {
    /* Similar to get_cursor_offset, but instead of reading we write data */
    offset /= 2;
    port_byte_out(REG_SCREEN_CTRL, 14);
    port_byte_out(REG_SCREEN_DATA, (unsigned char)(offset >> 8));
    port_byte_out(REG_SCREEN_CTRL, 15);
    port_byte_out(REG_SCREEN_DATA, (unsigned char)(offset & 0xff));
}

int get_offset(int col, int row) { return 2 * (row * MAX_COLS + col); }
int get_offset_row(int offset) { return offset / (2 * MAX_COLS); }
```

It does not print anything, but what is generated in a non-dynamic array prints.

Compile on Windows:

```
gcc -g -m32 -nostdlib -nostdinc -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -c kernel/kernel.c -o kernel/kernel.o -std=c99
gcc -g -m32 -nostdlib -nostdinc -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -c kernel/util.c -o kernel/util.o -std=c99
gcc -g -m32 -nostdlib -nostdinc -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -c drivers/ports.c -o drivers/ports.o -std=c99
gcc -g -m32 -nostdlib -nostdinc -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -c drivers/screen.c -o drivers/screen.o -std=c99
nasm -fbin boot/bootsect.asm -o boot/bootsect.bin
nasm -felf boot/kernel-entry.asm -o boot/kernel-entry.o
ld -mi386pe -o kernel.elf -Ttext 0x1000 boot/kernel-entry.o kernel/kernel.o kernel/util.o drivers/ports.o drivers/screen.o
objcopy -O binary kernel.elf kernel.bin
type boot\\bootsect.bin kernel.bin > os-image.bin
qemu-system-i386 -fda os-image.bin
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile, and there's no "dynamic char array", and "all signs are equal to zeros" does not seem to correspond to the question. Can you include a minimal reproducible example (perhaps including the diff between the code that "does not print" and that that does "print"). And mention what hardware you're using, and how you're compiling and running the code.

Comment: You have a `int offset` in one function, but all the others just have `offset` which is a little strange. You have functions `get_offset` and `get_offset_row` but they are not called.

Comment: the code works: print_char('A',-1,-1,RED_ON_WHITE);

Comment: Function `print_char` doesn't use its arguments `row` and `col`. The claimed `print_char(d[0],-1,-1,RED_ON_WHITE);` cannot work, it is outside any function.

Comment: this code works: print_char('A',-1,-1,RED_ON_WHITE);

Comment: Nope, not as posted.

Comment: Oh, I deleted the code with offset

Comment: `d` is a `char*` pointing to a literal constant string.  There is nothing "dynamic" about that.  It is not clear from the invalid code where or how that is declared.  It exists outside any function, so might be assumed to be static/global, but it is followed in your post by a function call that cannot exist outside a function.  Context is everything here - is that a separate code fragment?  If so, do not post it in the same code block as everything else - it makes the question very ambiguous.

Comment: Really though the question is about when you declare `char* d="hello world!!!";`, `d` does not point to the expected initialisation data (e.g. `d[0] !- 'h'`).  Everything else is irrelevant noise - especially the reference to "dynamic".  You are not attempting this without the aid of a debugger I hope?  It will be slow and frustrating progress otherwise.

Comment: For your own sanity: https://wiki.osdev.org/How_Do_I_Use_A_Debugger_With_My_OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified `-nostartfiles` making *you* responsible for the C runtime environment start-up and initialisation.  Part of that initialisation is to implement the static initialisers.  Without that:

```
char* d = "hello world!!!" ;
```

will do nothing.  It is not clear which if any of the object modules you have linked if any contain the start-up code. By convention there would be a crt0.o for that.

Comment: Thank you, but how can I implement my static initialiser?

Comment: I have already implemented my version of dynamic allocation

Comment: Dynamic allocation is irrelevant here - why do you think it is relevant?  https://wiki.osdev.org/Creating_a_C_Library#crt0.o